# Is Shopware 6 Uploaded Media Stored In The Database?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Where exactly are the (product) image files stored? I can't find the images in my Shopware 6 installation folders. If it is in the database, explain how it is done and which table because I have looked at the `media` table and can't seem to decode where the image file is.

Answer (score 1):

Public files are saved in `public/media`, while private files are in `files/media`.

the env variable `SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT` defines how the files are saved.
For example:

```
SHOPWARE_CDN_STRATEGY_DEFAULT=id
```

Answer (score 1):

As @zabus wrote, this is dependent on the CDN strategy.

Those strategies are implemented in https://github.com/shopware/platform/tree/trunk/src/Core/Content/Media/Pathname/PathnameStrategy, in case you want to know in detail how a path is generated, which happens on-the-fly.

There is a [WIP pull request to store the final path in the database](https://github.com/shopware/platform/pull/2692).